# Union of all possible combinations of certain events

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm trying to figure out whether there is a non brute-force method of calculating the union of all possible combinations of certain events. As an example, let's assume I have an unfair dice which I throw three times. I'm interested in calculating the probability of obtaining only 1's and 2's, asssuming that their probabilities are 0.15 and 0.05, respectively. 
Doing this by brute force, will result in the following:
$$
             0.05 \cdot 0.15 \cdot 2+0.05^2+0.15^2
$$
The question is whether there is any convinient shortcut/distribution for this problem. Assuming the N is 100 and not 3, for example - using brute force can be a hell.

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Isaac

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to calculate the complement, or the probability that there are no 1's or 2's in the outcomes. Then, you don't have to think about all the permutations of the 1's and 2's ...

Comment: If there is a union of events $A_1,\dots,A_k$ then first go for finding $P(A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_k)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$0.05 \cdot 0.15 \cdot 2+0.05^2+0.15^2=(0.05+0.15)^2$$

Comment: Oh! You're so right! (I feel a bit stupid...) . Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome (I know the feeling :-)).